# How doDeploy and host a PWA on a php webpage

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-pwa

I have built a PWA with ionic/angular and host on bluehost with https

when I try to link to the site index.html

I revise the following errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()polyfills.js:1     

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () styles.css:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()     manifest.webmanifest:1
```

among many other 404 errors.

If I use firebase it will work but I wish try hosting my own for testing.  Has anyone else had this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the directions here

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/pwa#making-your-angular-app-a-pwa

And then I used

https://www.pwabuilder.com

To see what was missing and could be improved.

Then went to

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

To edit the

```
ngsw-config.json
```

and

```
manifest.webmanifest
```